# Integral equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

For any $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, prove that $\int_0^4f(x(x-3)^2)dx=2\int_1^3f(x(x-3)^2)dx$. I tried many things, but nothing worked out. I observed that $g(x)+g(4-x)=4$ where $g(x)=x(x-3)^2$. Hence this action $x \rightarrow 4-x$ acts in some peculiar way. Please, any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe try to express each of $\int_0^1, \int_1^3, \int_3^4$ of $f(x(x-3)^2)dx$ as $\int_0^2 f(x)\cdot r(x) dx$ where $r(x)$ comes from the appropriate substitution? That might do the trick, or it might be insurmountingly difficult.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: It's from SEEMOUS 2017.

Comment: @HarryReed I can't the list of problems, can you help ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM http://www.seemous2017.smm.com.mk/problems/Problems_EN.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way to solve this may be to look at it sideways.

Let $g$ be a continuous strictly increasing function on $[a,b],$
let $f$ be a continuous function on $[g(a), g(b)],$
and let $h$ be the inverse of $g,$ that is,
$h(g(x)) = x$ whenever $a \leq x \leq b.$

Consider the integral 
$$ \int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx. $$

If we make the substitution $y = g(x),$ then $x = h(y)$
and $dx = h'(y)\,dy,$ so
$$ \int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(y) h'(y) \,dy. $$

The same equation is true if $g$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[g(b),g(a)],$ although in this case, since $g(b) < g(a),$ it may be desirable to put the bounds of the right-hand integral in the usual order, like this:
$$ \int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx = -\int_{g(b)}^{g(a)} f(y) h'(y) \,dy. $$

For $g = x(x-3)^2$ on $[0,4],$ I would consider three different domains
separately: $g_1,$ a strictly increasing function defined on $[1,0]$;
$g_2,$ a strictly decreasing function defined on $[1,3]$; and
$g_3,$ a strictly increasing function defined on $[3,4].$
Let the inverses of these functions be respectively $h_1,$ $h_2,$ and $h_3.$
Then
$$
\int_1^3 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx = \int_1^3 f(g_2(x))\,dx 
= - \int_0^4 f(y)h_2'(y)\,dy
$$
and
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx + \int_3^4 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx &=
 \int_0^1 f(g_1(x))\,dx + \int_3^4 f(g_3(x))\,dx \\
&= \int_0^4 f(y)h_1'(y)\,dy + \int_0^4 f(y)h_3'(y)\,dy \\
&= \int_0^4 f(y)\left( h_1'(y) + h_3'(y) \right)\,dy .
\end{align}

So if $h_1'(y) + h_3'(y) = - h_2'(y),$ then
$$\int_0^1 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx + \int_3^4 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx
 = \int_1^3 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx,$$
and therefore $\int_0^4 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx = 2\int_1^3 f(x(x-3)^2)\,dx,$
as was to be shown.

After some playing around with the inverse of $g(x) = x(x-3)^2$
[in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x(x-3)%5E2)
(see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%2F2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+-+%282%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+2),
[here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%28-i+sqrt%283%29-1%29%2F2%29%28%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%2F2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+-+%28%28i+sqrt%283%29-1%29%2F2%29%282%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+2),
and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%28i+sqrt%283%29-1%29%2F2%29%28%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%2F2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+-+%28%28-i+sqrt%283%29-1%29%2F2%29%282%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4x%29-x%2B2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+2)),
it seems to me that
\begin{align}
h_1(y) &= 2 - u - \frac1u,\\
h_2(y) &= 2 - \omega u - \frac1{\omega u}
        = 2 - \omega u - \omega^2\frac1u,\\
h_3(y) &= 2 - \omega^2 u - \frac1{\omega^2 u}
        = 2 - \omega^2 u - \omega\frac1u,
\end{align}
where 
$$u = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x} - x + 2}{2}} = e^{i(\cos(1-x/2))/3},$$
from which it follows that $h_1(y) + h_2(y) + h_3(y) = 6,$
from which you can get the result you need.

---

**Update:** The inverse functions are really laborious to compute, even with Wolfram Alpha. For the reference of anyone else who looks at this question, a far better idea is in the answer posted by Frank Zermelo, which completely avoids constructing the inverse functions.

Comment: Sincerely, I do not know how would one compute those inverse functions. That is why I will write an answer based on yours where you don't need to compute the inverse functions at all. Thanks for the idea! Great solution!

Comment: @daniel I think we are both "rearranging" the values of $g$ on the interval of integration. The symmetry is a little tricky, though; the integral $\int_0^1 f(g(x))dx$ is (probably) not equal to $\int_3^4 f(g(x))dx,$ and the trick is they have to add up to $\int_1^3 f(g(x))dx.$ The fact that the integrals add up when it's just $\int g\,dx$ doesn't really help AFAIK. You may be on a correct track, but I didn't sense that you'd gotten to the finish.

Comment: Just posted below my remark on your answer. What's actually funny is that you never use that action $x \rightarrow 4-x$ in any way, while I originally thought it's the key to the solution.

Comment: So $\int_1^3 g =\int_3^4 (4-g)$ implies $\int_0^1 f(g) = \int_3^4 f(4-g)$ is false? (Yes I agree I had not gotten to the finish).

Comment: @daniel Technically yes, I think that implication is not a good inference, but the right-hand side is nevertheless true because of the symmetry of $g.$ I got a bit stuck trying to figure out what to do next, however, so I started over. But just because I gave up doesn't mean the approach can't work.

Comment: So I think the link I added to my answer contains a proof of the claim above. I haven't worked through it yet but it seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Using the OP's notation, $g(x)=x(x-3)^2,$ it seems that the symmetry of the cubic on the interval in question is a key. Other functions with this symmetry can be used to construct similar functional equations.

Example:

Let $h = 4x$ on $[0,1]$, $h=-2x+6$ on $[1,3]$ and $h =4 x-12$ on $[3,4].$ Then for $h$ also, exploiting symmetry, and $f$ as in the OP,

$$ \int_0^1 f(h(x))dx +\int_3^4f(h(x))dx = \int_1^3f(h(x))dx$$ or

$$\int_0^4f(h) = 2\int_1^3 f(h). $$

For $g$ we have that

$\int_0^1 g = \int_3^4 4-g,$ and $ \int_3^4 g = \int_0^1 4-g.$

We already have by symmetry for $g$ that $\int_1^3g = \int_1^34-g$ so

$\int_1^3 g + \int_1^3 4-g = 2\int_1^3 g =\int_1^3 4 = 8.$ So for $g,$

$2\int_1^3 g = \int_0^1 g+\int_3^4 g+\int_1^3 g = \int_0^4 g.$

Then I think using the definition of $f$, the Riemann integral, continuity, we can show that on $[0,1],[3,4],$ if

$\int_0^1 g = \int_3^4 4-g$ then $\int_0^1f(g) = \int_3^4 f(4-g).$

Likewise, if $\int_1^3 g = \int_1^3 4-g,$ then $\int_1^3 f(g) = \int_1^3 f(4-g).$

These last follow from the naive observation (in this narrow context)** that if $g$ takes on a set of values in $[a,b]$ rearranging those values, loosely speaking, will not alter the value of the integral on the interval. The same is true of $f(g).$

** **Edit:** By "this narrow context" I mean symmetry. This conclusion is proved [in the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184465/composition-of-functions-question).

---

Sample calculation for $h$. Using $f(x) = \cos x,$

$\int_0^1 \cos(4x)dx+\int_3^4 \cos(4x-12)dx = \int_1^3 \cos(-2x+6)dx\approx -.3784.$

$\int_0^1 4x dx+\int_3^4 (4x-12) dx = \int_1^3 (-2x+6) dx = 4.$

Sample calculation for $g.$ Using $f(x) = \cos x,$

$\int_0^1 \cos(x(x-3)^2)dx = \int_3^4 \cos(4-x(x-3)^2)dx\approx -.486.$

Answer (score 2):

This is just a follow-up on @DavidK's answer. Since it seems very hard to compute the inverses of $g(x)=x(x-3)^2$, I will provide a solution where we don't need to compute them.

Let $h_1(x),h_2(x),h_3(x)$ be inverses of $g(x)$ on the intervals $[0,1],[1,3],[3,4].$ We know by the monotonicity of $g(x)$ that $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,4]$,  $g:[1,3]\rightarrow [0,4]$, $g:[3,4]\rightarrow [0,4]$ are surjective functions, also proving that the domains of definition of $h_1(x),h_2(x),h_3(x)$ is $[0,4]$ for all three of them.

By David K's answer, it is sufficient to prove that $h_1(y)+h_2(y)+h_3(y)=6$ for all $y \in [0,4]$.

Take $y \in [0,4]$. By the above mentioned surjectivity of $g(x)$, there exists $x_1 \in [0,1], x_2 \in [1,3],x_3\in[3,4]$ with $g(x_1)=g(x_2)=g(x_3)=y$. By the property of inverse functions, we know that $h_i(g(x_i))=x_i$, for all $i=1,2,3.$ Hence $$h_1(y)+h_2(y)+h_3(y)=h_1(g(x_1))+h_2(g(x_2))+h_3(g(x_3))=x_1+x_2+x_3$$
the statement to prove is equivalent of proving that: If $x_1 \in [0,1], x_2 \in [1,3],x_3\in[3,4]$ with $g(x_1)=g(x_2)=g(x_3)$, then $x_1+x_2+x_3=6$.

Suppose $g(x_1)=g(x_2)=g(x_3)=y$ for some $y\in [0,4]$. Let $P(x)=g(x)-y=x^3-6x^2+9x-y$, a cubic polynomial in $x$. We know by hypothesis that $P(x_1)=P(x_2)=P(x_3)=0$, hence $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of $P$. By the Vieta's formula, we get $x_1+x_2+x_3=6$, and we are done.

Comment: I don't know how to tag David K's name into my answer. If someone knows how to do it, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Fantastic! I felt there ought to be a way that didn't involve solving a cubic, but I did not see this.