# Number of solutions of $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + \cdots + n x_n = p$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

> Given a non-negative integer $p$. What is the number of solutions of $x_1+2x_2+3x_3 + \cdots + nx_n = p$, where the $x_i$'s are non-negative integers.

Can we answer this by using number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3 + \cdots + x_m = q$ for any $m,q$?

Comment: Did you learn generating functions? Seems like they would be apropos..

Comment: The number of solutions to the first equation, is equal to the number of solutions to the second equation for $m=n$ and $p=q$ and all $x_i$s are different, and it's called the number $p_m(q)$ of partitions of $q$ into exactly $m$ parts ". There is a lot of mathematical research in how to compute these numbers, but they don't have a closed form, except complicated formalus and relating to coefficients of generating functions which are also hard to compute

Comment: @Elaqqad How are the number of solutions same. I am very sure they are not. I think you misunderstood the question. I can provide a counterexample if you need.

Comment: that's not what I wrote !, they are the same if we require in the second equution the $x_i$ s to be all distincts

Answer (score 2):

The number of nonnegative integer solutions of $x_1 + 2 x_2 + \cdots + n x_n = p$, where $p \geq 0$, is the coefficient of $t^p$ in the following generating function [JDL]

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-t^k} = \frac{1}{(1-t) (1-t^2) \cdots (1-t^n)}$$

---

[JDL] Jesús A. De Loera, [The Many Aspects of Counting Lattice Points in Polytopes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/RECENT_WORK/semesterberichte.pdf).

Comment: Is there any closed form solution? Or any $\mathcal{O}(n)$ solution or something like that.

Comment: I don't know. Take a look at the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 1):

The number of solutions of $x_1+2x_2+ \cdots +nx_n=p$ is given by the coefficient of $x^{p}$ in
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2) \cdots (1-x^n) } 
\end{eqnarray*}

The number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+ \cdots +x_m=q$ is given by the coefficient of $x^{q}$ in
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^m } 
\end{eqnarray*}
So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: maybe you should answer why the answer is no , because the question is : are the coefficients of the two generating functions related in some way ? ( using the generating function is just another terminology, just rephrasing  the question in another way)

Comment: Is there any way to evaluate the former expression?

Comment: Yes. An explanation for this "No" would be great.

Comment: I am still stuck on this one from yesterday ... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180428/integral-equation

Comment: The latter expression is easily is easily evaluated $\binom{q}{m-1}$ . I am not aware of an easy way to evaluate the former expression ... so I guess there is no easy way to relate the two. ... this still avoids the crunch question ... sorry :-)

Comment: I know about the latter one. Is there any method to compute the former without brute force solution? $\mathcal{O}(n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, something like that?