# Calculate number of solutions for $\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot x_i = n$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a general method to find the number of non-negative integral solutions for
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot x_i = n $$

Comment: I have no good answer, but it seems to me that you are opening the door to the theory of [*integer partitions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: How about these [Number of solutions of $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + \cdots + n x_n = p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181690/number-of-solutions-of-x-1-2x-2-3x-3-cdots-n-x-n-p), [Number of solutions of $x_1+2x_2+\cdots+kx_k=n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053319/number-of-solutions-of-x-12x-2-cdotskx-k-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot x_i = n$$ can be rewritten as $$1 \le y_1 \le y_2 \le \ldots \le y_m \le k,\,\, \sum_{j=1}^m y_j = n$$ where $m$ is not fixed. This is a *restricted partition* (specifically a *partition of $n$ into parts not exceeding $k$*), and the values you seek are tabulated in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as [A026820](//oeis.org/A026820).

Note in particular that OEIS gives the formula $T(n,k) = T(n,k-1) + T(n-k,k)$ which has a simple combinatoric explanation: a solution to $$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot x_i = n$$ either has $x_k = 0$, in which case it's a solution to $$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i\cdot x_i = n$$ or it has $x_k > 0$, in which case it's a solution to $$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot (x_i - [i = k]) = n-k$$

Closed forms are available by applying the work of Bruiner and Ono on weak Maass forms, but I suspect that that is currently not within your reach, and I know it's not within mine.

For small $k$, [closed forms have been enumerated](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/oPARTITIONS1) by Doron Zeilberger, although he would prefer to credit his computer, Shalosh B. Ekhad. A brief explanation is given [in a joint paper with Andrew Sills](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/pmn.pdf).

Comment: The recurrence will be good enough for me. Thanks!